# about Calabash for iOS

Tags: ios, calabash

I have a code:

```
wait_for(options) do
    views = query("view marked:'al_activity_controller'")
    foundedView = views.first;
    views.count != 0 #return value for "wait_for" block
    calabash_warn("tap on activity")
end
```

if I comment the line calabash_warn("tap on activity") all works fine.

In other case I never leave wait_for block. And I got timeout. Why so?

As I know calabash_warn have return type void.

Comment: I got it. The problem was in device. I tried to launch iPhone app on the iPad device. When I switch device setting to iPad - all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The Calabash `wait_for*` methods wait for the *last* statement to eval to true, otherwise they timeout.  The `calabash_warn` method does not have a defined return type, so it never returns true.

Just a heads up, the `calabash_warn` method is slated for deprecation as public method.